# Append SQLAlchemy results to python list faster

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

I have results (~60000 rows) from some db query that I need to add to a list.

The code looks like this :

```
hosts = connection.execute(some_query)
for host in hosts:
    mylist.append(host['display_name'])
```

However, iterating over all the items and appending them to the list is very slow.
How can I make it faster ? I've looked on https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#loops but this doesn't seem to apply to my case.

Comment: Why do you need them in a list?

Comment: The list is part of a dict that I json.dumps() later. That's for an Ansible inventory plugin, I basically copied on [the other ones](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/tree/devel/plugins/inventory).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found out that most of the time was spent in the fetchone function of oursql (the MySQL connector I use with SQLAlchemy) which seems to be called for each iteration of the for loop.

Switching to the MySQL-Python (mysqldb) connector made the script run in ~3s instead of ~4m.

Answer (score 1):

Use [List comprehesions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) instead of the foor loop.

```
mylist = [host['display_name'] for host in hosts]
```

But also check if the performance is not in executing the query itself.

Comment: I've done some mesurement and this doesn't seem to improve things, the script takes > 4m to run in any case, it is even marginally slower.

Comment: Really, take a look at the SQL query itself and measure its performance. If it takes long to execute this query directly via the database, then you know that there is not much to optimize on sqlalchemy side. If you do not have the raw query, you can see it in the logs by enabling `engine.echo = True`. btw, i changed the answer to collect only the `display_name` field.

Comment: I should have mentionned it, but I already looked at the query and it runs in a few ms, so isn't worth optimizing since the whole script takes minutes to run.